# Indegree or in-degree

Tags: hyphenation, programming

I've been reading network science books and I've been puzzled by use of in-degree and indegree. It seems both are used but are they both correct? In graph theory I have seen mainly indegree but in computer science in-degree.

Comment: Are you sure they mean the same thing? _Field_ means one thing in _magnetic field_, but a totally different thing in _complex field_.

Comment: [***mathworks***](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/digraph.indegree.html) has this definition for a Matlab function: *D = **indegree(G)** returns a column vector containing the **in-degree** of each node in G.* I assume Matlab allows function names to include hyphens, so that suggests they're seen as orthographies of equivalent meaning and status.

Comment: @FF Have you a dictionary giving 'orthography' = 'one particular acceptable spelling of a given word'? I'm sure OED will have it, but can't find it in the freebies.